# Downloads (pdf's) in Customer account

Tags: admin, customer, adminhtml, download-link

Anyone knows some way to able admin share files with magento users?
I want a file uploader like this:

[image]
This is a magento module from ITORIS but is too expensive, the module have to many functions what i dont need, i need some more cheap, only with that function like image.

Thank's in advance!

Comment: joao, welcome to MSE... Please take support from extension provider

Comment: Thank You!
Im waiting for news from ITORIS about this, to find solution to use parcial code, 
Thanks again